# Query in PostgreSQL with large quantity of squid access requests

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, squid

Hello people, I'm using a log daemon (https://github.com/paranormal/blooper) in Squid Proxy to put access log into PostreSQL and I make a Trigger Function:

```sql
DECLARE
  newtime varchar := EXTRACT (MONTH FROM NEW."time")::varchar;
  newyear varchar := EXTRACT (YEAR FROM NEW."time")::varchar;
  user_name varchar := REPLACE (NEW.user_name, '.', '_');
  partname varchar := newtime || '_' ||  newyear;
  tablename varchar := user_name || '.accesses_' || partname;
BEGIN

  IF NEW.user_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ' || user_name;

    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '
    || tablename
    || '('
    || 'CHECK (user_name = ''' || NEW.user_name || ''' AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "time") = ' || newtime || ' AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM "time") = ' || newyear || ')'
    || ') INHERITS (public.accesses)';

    EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS access_index_' || partname || '_user_name ON ' || tablename || ' (user_name)';
    EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS access_index_' || partname || '_time ON ' || tablename || ' ("time")';

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' SELECT $1.*' USING NEW;
  END IF;

  RETURN NULL;
END;
```

The main function of it is make a table partition by user_name and by month-year of the access, inhering from a master clean table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.accesses
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('accesses_id_seq'::regclass),
  "time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  time_response integer,
  mac_source macaddr,
  ip_source inet NOT NULL,
  ip_destination inet,
  user_name character varying(40),
  http_status_code numeric(3,0) NOT NULL,
  http_reply_size bigint NOT NULL,
  http_request_method character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  http_request_url character varying(4166) NOT NULL,
  http_content_type character varying(100),
  squid_hier_code character varying(20),
  squid_request_status character varying(50),
  user_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT accesses_http_request_method_fkey FOREIGN KEY (http_request_method)
  REFERENCES public.http_requests (method) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT accesses_http_status_code_fkey FOREIGN KEY (http_status_code)
  REFERENCES public.http_statuses (code) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT accesses_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

The main problem is get the sum of http_reply_size grouping by user_name and time, my query is:

```sql
SELECT
  "time",
  user_name,
  sum(http_reply_size)
FROM
  accesses
WHERE
  extract(epoch from "time") BETWEEN 1516975122 AND 1516996722
GROUP BY
  "time",
  user_name
```

But this query is very slow in the server (3'237'976 rows currently in 2 days only). So, PostgreSQL has something to optimize a query with that need, or I need to use another SQL or NoSQL system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include a `CHECK` condition on each partition so doesn't have to scan all tables.

In my case is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || table_name || '( 
        CONSTRAINT ' || pk || ' PRIMARY KEY (avl_id),
        CHECK ( event_time >= ''' || begin_time || ''' AND event_time < ''' || end_time || ''' )
        ) INHERITS (avl_db.avl);
```

Also don't use `extract(epoch from "time")` that will need to calculate the value for each row and can't use the index you create for `"time"`

so use like this to get advantage of the index.

```
WHERE "time" >= '2018-01-01'::timestamp with time zone
  and "time" <  '2018-02-01'::timestamp with time zone
```

Comment: Most like it the second tip is the most important.

Comment: For the `CHECK`, already i have the CHECK with user_name and the month, so i need split in more grannulaty time, maybe seconds??

Comment: Sorry I miss that. Then the problem is the `EXTRACT`

Comment: whait, is not ended the query yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163978/discussion-between-luis-felipe-dominguez-vega-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: The users's access tables are in another scheme with their name